# BUTTON to move data from multiple google sheets into one master

Tags: javascript

My boss told to move same set of data from 40 multiple google sheets into one master sheets which are filled by 40 people separately currently am working on it with an ADD on function
is there any way to put a submit button on each sheets so that when user fill the data and click on submit button the data go direct to the master sheets ?
I have the script which is working fine with sheets but the only cons of that is the script only combine the tabs into same spreadsheet
here is code :

```
const masterSheet = "ASM-A30";
const masterSheetFormulaCell = "A2";
const ignoreSheets = ["Verified NDRx","Business Tracker","NDRX","PMT_EBx","PMT_EBx.","NDRx PMT Business Tracker.","Analysis"];
const dataRange = "A2:AA";
const checkRange = "A2:A" ;
//end set variables

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() ;

ignoreSheets.push(masterSheet) ;

const allsheets = ss.getSheets() ;

const filteredListofSheets = allsheets.filter(s => ignoreSheets.indexOf(s.getSheetName()) == -1);

let formulaArray = filteredListofSheets.map(s => `FILTER({'${s.getSheetName()}'!${dataRange},"${s.getSheetName()} - Row "&ROW('${s.getSheetName()}'!${dataRange})}, '${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRange}<>"")`);
let formulaText = "={" + formulaArray.join(";")+ "}"

//console.1og( formulaText) ;
ss. getSheetByName(masterSheet).getRange(masterSheetFormulaCell) .setFormula(formulaText) ;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
const ignoreSheets = ["Verified NDRx","Business Tracker","NDRX","PMT_EBx","PMT_EBx.","NDRx PMT Business Tracker.","Analysis"];
const masterSheet = "ASM-A30";
function compile() {
  let result = []
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().filter(s => ignoreSheets.indexOf(s.getSheetName()) == -1).forEach((s,i) => {
    let [headers, ...data] = s.getDataRange().getValues()
    if (i == 0) { result.push(headers.flat()) }
    data.forEach(r => result.push(r))
  })
  if(result.length) {
    var master = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(masterSheet) 
    master.clearContents()
    master.getRange(1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result)
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Updated!');
  }
}
```

to add rows, change

```
if (i == 0) {  }
```

and try

```
  var master = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(masterSheet) 
  // master.clearContents()
  master.getRange(+master.getLastRow()+1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Updated!');
```

Comment: This will combine the data of 1st tabs from al the 40 sheets but is there anything that we can do for data to move to the master sheet only when user push a submit button in there sheets respectively ? is what is asked for -?

Comment: it could be done if everybody has access to the master, moreover we need to replace previous data from each spreadsheet, I will have a look for this asap

Comment: After a short reflexion, it appears that it is too complex if 2 at least of the 40 guys will ask for update at the same time. So, what I suggest is to put a trigger to automatically update on opening the master spreadsheet.

Comment: ids.forEach((id, i) => {
    let [headers, ...data] = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ids).getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues() ,HERE it says.......... Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp.

Comment: have you updates ths ids with yours? do you have permission do access to theses spreadsheets?

Comment: YES ,I have update IDs of all the 40 sheets and allowed the excess to it after execution of the script its giving this error

Comment: Can you tray again "as is", I have introduced my own shared spreadsheets in the published code.

Comment: Still it says -*Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp."

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding, I have updated my answer since all data are in different tabs in the same spreadsheet

Comment: Script is working fine now the only flaw of the script is that after putting it on trigger it is throwing bunch of same data every times  script runs (it should throw the updated data Only )

Comment: how can we see new data ? that was not specified in your request

Comment: see my update ...

Comment: Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.

Comment: that means that one sheet is empty, so add a test `if(result.length)`

Comment: Mike Steelson the script runs fine now ,thank you so much for the gesture , i really appreciate it I am new to App Script and not much familiar with It. I know you're already a immortal ,Please accept my apology for a poor skills. thanks alot